# Is removing unnecessary smileys and ellipses a valid suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I see a few questions containing multiple smileys and ellipses (the "...").

Two examples of this scenario:

1. This `ng-idle` is not supporting.... :( The `$idleProvider` throws an error :(
2. I'm new to angularjs... I tried an approach with `ng-idle`... The `idle.watch()` is not working as expected...

Other than that, there is nothing to improve in those questions; the content and code are clear and aligned properly.

The smileys and ellipses are **not affecting the readability** of the question.

So my question is, can I suggest an edit to remove those smileys and ellipses? Will it be considered a valid edit?

Comment: I have to admit, it kind of *does* feel like there's way too many questions with "..." all over the place.

Comment: Stuff like "I'm new to angularjs" can be edited out as well. Guaranteed there's _something_ else to edit in a question like this, even if it's just tags.

Comment: I reworded the question a little bit; let me know if I changed it too much

Comment: I always remove ellipses, "thank you", "I am new to Foo", and similar noise. A suggested edit that does the same would get my approval.

Comment: @DennisMeng: The rewording is fine, the content is now much clear, Thanks.

Comment: "The smileys and ellipses are not affecting the readability" - I disagree, too many of those and the post is a mess.

Comment: I've always wondered..... where people learn to write..... like this.... The unnecessary periods do affect the readability.

Comment: as a reviewer, aren't you supposed to decide that? it's up to *you*. others might disagree, which is why we have multiple reviewers.

Comment: Even worse than "..." is ".." I don't know why some people just *have* to stop at two dots, as if three would be way too much effort.

Comment: @sgroves: The reason for asking on meta is that reviewers are not born with an innate knowledge of all the ins and outs of good editing practice, so asking for advice on training one's judgement to be more discerning (without necessarily losing one's own viewpoint) is a very good thing.

Comment: Those aren't even proper ellipses (…), just three dots. Nuke 'em! (And I say that as someone who occasionally employs ellipses and smileys not only in comments but also in answers, albeit rarely.)

Comment: ... hm, ... ok ... :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, I think so. In the same way that improving grammar or removing statements like "sorry, I'm new to <language X>" are valid edits.

Comment: To be honest, if you have less than 2000 rep (so you need to have your edits vetted, and you're getting rep for the edit), and this is the only thing that you're changing, then it falls into the "does not improve the readability of the question" category IMO. Take some more time to really improve other parts of the question, then certainly it's ok to also remove the ellipses and smileys.

Comment: There is some merit to what you're saying. But it's not more or less difficult to review than an edit that just fixes indentation issues of code and it certainly does improve the quality of the post.

Comment: I've noticed an increase of obnoxious edits by certain users in the last week.  These edits only consist of removing "Thank you" and "I'm new to Language X".  I don't see why they should get any rep for that at all, as it is something that a 3rd grader can do.

Answer (score 17):

The post has to be **clearly** better after the edit for me to approve an edit.    This is even more important on old posts that are getting few views.

So just removing one smileys, is likely to get rejected by me, but if you also remove a "thank you" and improve the formatting then I may accept it.

**Therefore don't search for smileys to remove!**,  But do remove them if the post needs editing for another reason.

Answer (score -24):

Possibly try to comment first asking the OP to fix it up before attempting other steps - if the question can really substantially be improved this way.

Keep in mind that SO is heavily used, so just because you spot it does not mean you have to act on it (beyond that comment to instruct the OP). Someone with enough internet points to directly edit the question might just come along and make your day. In popular tags such as the major languages I see questions being edited faster than I can blink.

Comment: The additional noise of a comment is not worth it to remove a smiley.  Just edit it out.

Comment: Sick of people using "delete" to remove posts they don't like. That's not what "delete" is for. Downvote and move on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit open a meta issue about it - I'd vote for a culture change on that.

Comment: I think I miscommunicated quite a bit to warrant so many downvotes. The intention was to edit when you can, I was taking into consideration the special case where you don't have enough points to do it yourself which means your edits have to be reviewed - which for small changes such as this is overkill.